# HTTP post request doesn't respond on production environment (war with tomcat server)

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, war

I have implemented a `PerformHttpPostRequest` function which is supposed to send a post request contains a JSON type body and get a JSON response via Apache HttpClient.

```
public static String PerformHttpPostRequest(String url, String requestBody) throws IOException {

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestBody);

httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();

return (new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"))).readLine();
}
```

The problem is, the code works perfect on developing environment, but when running the war file with a tomcat server but the request is not executed.

I've tried adding several catch blocks such as `IOException`, `Exception` and the code doesn't get there.

I've added debug prints which demonstrated that the code stops responding at the `client.execute(...)` command.

The function is called inside a `try` block, and after executing the `.execute(...)` command the code does get to the `finally` block.

I've already searched for a similar problem and didn't find an answer.

Is it a known issue? Does anyone have any idea of what can cause that? Or how can I fix it?

Comment: can you check pinging the ip, or try to hit the service from a rest client like postman. At first glance it looks like some fire-wall is blocking.

Comment: What are the libraries and frameworks used?

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala I've already used postman, the server is available and working fine.

Comment: @SajithNeyomal I'm using org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients liabries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Talor nice to meet you,
Please try to use HttpURLConnection to solve this issue like so:

[Java - sending HTTP parameters via POST method easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)

Have a nice day.

el profesor

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. Apache HttpClient does in fact work, so the solution isn't just "use another library". Of course, the question doesn't even describe what the problem is, so the solution could just as easily have been "have you tried restarting your computer?"

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with RestTemplate.

```
RequestObject requestObject = new RequestObject();
        requestObject.setKey("abcd");
        requestObject.setEndpoint(serviceEndPoint);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<RequestObject> requestBody = new HttpEntity<RequestObject>(
                requestObject);

        ResponseEntity<RequestObject> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                serviceEndPoint, requestBody, RequestObject.class);
```

Its very simple and hassle free, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can try out.
 - Try to do ping/curl from that box where you are running tomcat.
 - Try to have a test method which make a get request to a server which is always reachable. For ex google.com and print the status. That way you could be able to know that you code is actually working or not in server env. 
Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the code doesn't pass beyond `client.execute(...)` but it does execute the `finally` block in the calling code, then you can find out what caused the aborted execution by adding this catch block to the `try` block that contains the `finally`:

```
catch(Throwable x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

`Throwable` is the superclass for all exception and error classes, so catching a Throwable will catch everything.